# I want the rows in 2nd dataframe to replace corresponding rows with same unique ID in the 1st dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, merge

I have 2 tables

1. `x`
2. `y`

Both have different number of rows.

Columns "a" and "b" together act as unique key.

I want the rows in our `y` dataframe to replace the rows in `x` dataframe which have common "a" and "b" column values.

```py
x=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,2,3,3,np.nan,5],
                "b":[12,13,14,15,16,17,18],
                "c":["japan",np.nan,"india",np.nan,np.nan,"france","brazil"],
                "d":[12,15,10,np.nan,11,6,20]})
```

Result:

[image]

```py
y=pd.DataFrame({"a":[2,2,3,3],
                "b":[13,14,15,16],
                "c":[np.nan,"india","sweden","spain"],
                "d":[15,10,25,11]})
```

[image]

Required output:

[image]

I tried multiple methods like merge(),update() but its not working , please help

Answer (score 2):

Use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
out = x[['a', 'b']].merge(y, on=['a', 'b'], how='left').combine_first(x)
```

Output:

```
     a   b       c     d
0  1.0  12   japan  12.0
1  2.0  13     NaN  15.0
2  2.0  14   india  10.0
3  3.0  15  sweden  25.0
4  3.0  16   spain  11.0
5  NaN  17  france   6.0
6  5.0  18  brazil  20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If `a` and `b` together act as unique keys, you can set them as the index and then use `combine_first` as @mozway has suggested.

```py
x = x.set_index(["a", "b"])
y = y.set_index(["a", "b"])

out = x.combine_first(y)
```

```
             c     d
a   b               
1.0 12   japan  12.0
2.0 13     NaN  15.0
    14   india  10.0
3.0 15  sweden  25.0
    16   spain  11.0
NaN 17  france   6.0
5.0 18  brazil  20.0
```

You can optionally reset the index after

```py
out.reset_index()
```

```
     a   b       c     d
0  1.0  12   japan  12.0
1  2.0  13     NaN  15.0
2  2.0  14   india  10.0
3  3.0  15  sweden  25.0
4  3.0  16   spain  11.0
5  NaN  17  france   6.0
6  5.0  18  brazil  20.0
```

References

- [`pd.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
- [`pd.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)